# Update Entity Framework database results in "The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign key properties is non-nullable"

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I'm trying to update my database tables, but I keep getting an foreign key error.

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, 
>   the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

I have two tables with auto populated data using a context class and a `ContextInitializer` class.

**Table 1**: (`Bookings`) is created with this model:

```
public class Booking
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BookingNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime OutboundDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReturnDate { get; set; }
    public string Route { get; set; }
    public string ReturnRoute { get; set; }
    public string Passengers { get; set; }
    public string Pet { get; set; }
    public string VehicleType { get; set; }

    // Passengers
    public virtual ICollection<Passenger> PassengersList { get; set; }
}
```

**Table 2** (`Passenger`) is created with this model:

```
public enum PassengerType
{
    Adult, Children, Infant
}

public enum Title
{
    Mr, Mrs
}

public class Passenger
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BookingId { get; set; }
    public Title? Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public PassengerType? PassengerType { get; set; }
}
```

Passenger table has a foreign key to the booking table. One "Booking" can have multiple passengers, that why I use the `ICollection` list.

**Update**

Have edited my method to be like this:

```
public bool Execute(Booking booking)
    {
        // Get booking from database
        var bookingFromDatabase = _db.Bookings.Find(booking.Id);

        if (bookingFromDatabase != null)
        {
                // Map passengersList
                bookingFromDatabase.PassengersList.Clear();
                foreach (var passenger in booking.PassengersList)
                {
                    bookingFromDatabase.PassengersList.Add(passenger);
                }

                // Save changes in database
                _db.Entry(bookingFromDatabase).State = EntityState.Modified;           
                _db.SaveChanges();

                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I still getting the error. Can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. I know there is something wrong with the foreign keys and entity framework can't map them proberly.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: is `booking.PassengersList` null? If it is, create a new collection so that it is an empty list.

Comment: No its not.. it has 2 passengers in it (the one a tested) just with different names to the passengers.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are multiple issues with your code:

```
// Map passengersList
bookingFromDatabase.PassengersList = booking.PassengersList;
```

Here, you are changing the reference itself and it will not be tracked anymore. One way (not very efficient when the list is long) is to clear existing list and add elements from the new one (not tested):

```
bookingFromDatabase.PassengersList.Clear();
foreach (var passenger in booking.PassengersList)
   bookingFromDatabase.PassengersList.Add(passenger);
```

The attach from

```
// Save changes in database
_db.Bookings.Attach(bookingFromDatabase);
```

is useless since bookingFromDatabase is fetched using the context and it is tracked.

In order to inform EF data context that you are updating bookingFromDatabase, you can do something like this:

```
_db.Entry(bookingFromDatabase).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

before calling `_db.SaveChanges()`;

Comment: Okay.. thanks for your quick reply.. will try read this and understand it.. Will let you know if it changes anything :) Good day to you!